# Why isn't the post returning the TableID?

Tags: php

When I set the $test1 variable to a number instead of the $_POST the code works as expected. However, when I set it to post the TableID is doesn't return anything. I have set up some out prints and they are all returning the correct results so can anyone tell me why the TableID isn't getting posted to the PHP session?

PHP at top of page before the html statement.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

        $test1 = $_POST['TableID'];

        $_SESSION["table_id"] = $test1;

        header("Location:test.php");

    }
```

Form being used within the PHP file.

```
  echo "<form action=" .  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . " method=\"POST\">\n";
                                        echo "  <div class=\"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3\">\n";
                                        echo "      <div class=\"thumbnail well\">\n";
                                        echo "          <div class=\"thumbnail-pad\">\n";
                                        echo "              <br/>\n";
                                        echo "              <h4 align=\"center\">\n" . $info['TestName'] . "</h4>\n";
                                        echo "              <br/>\n";
                                        echo "             <h5 align=\"center\"> Table id is: " . $info['TableID'] . " </h5>";

                                        echo "              <input type='hidden' value='" . $info['TableID'] . "'>";
                                        echo "              <div align=\"center\"><button type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" align=\"center\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-md col-lg-12\">Test</button></div>\n";
                                        echo "          </div>\n";
                                        echo "      </div>\n";
                                        echo "  </div>\n";
                                        echo "</form>\n";
```

Comment: Add `name=\"TableID\"` to your hidden field. POST is looking for a named element called `TableID`. Plus, make sure `session_start();` is loaded, since you are using sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give input name, otherwise it won't be visible on form submit:

```
<input type='hidden' name='TableID' value='" . $info['TableID'] . "'>";
```